# What should I use for multiple update transactional key value data storage?

Tags: database, json, key-value, key-value-store

I'm researching data storage for a new personal project, a collaboration within a small team that is not expected to grow. I'm looking for the right database tool for the job.

1. Key value storage (JSON blobs)
2. Supports multiple update transactions
   (e.g. update two values at once within a transaction, or abort the
   whole thing)
3. Does not need to resolve conflicts (we'll just write a
   retry model)
4. Plays nicely with node.js and/or .NET
5. The lighter weight, the better

Answer (score 1):

LMDB is transactional, using MVCC single-writer so it can never have conflicts or deadlocks. It is the smallest fully transactional K/V store in existence. It is also the fastest and most reliable. Bindings for C#/.Net and node.js are available.

(I am the author of LMDB)  http://symas.com/mdb/

Comment: considering you're the author, I think I can ask where can I find some documentation on how to create/use a database in the C#.net binding. it's nowhere to be found.

Comment: I didn't write the C# bindings, but the main docs are at http://symas.com/mdb/doc/ which would have been obvious if you read the page I linked above.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb fits:

1. It stores documents, works natively with BSON (similar to JSON), converts to JSON.
2. It supports [transactions](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/perform-two-phase-commits/)
3. It'll be happy with you updating documents multiple times
4. It plays very very nicely with node.js - `npm install mongoose` gives you the http://mongoosejs.com/
5. It's fairly lightweight - easy to install